# How to turn off the bells and whistles of myeclipse

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I want to turn off the bells and whistles of myeclipse 8.6 like validations etc. I just want to use it as a simple text editor. I dont know from where i should do this.

Answer (score 2):

why not to use vim then? :) .. or the classic eclipse distro?